# Maximum limit for COPY FROM STDIN in postgres

Tags: postgresql

May I know what is the maximum number of records that can be inserted. In my program, it works for around 20,000 file reading and inserting into db. But the total count is 400,000. When I try with 400,000 files, it is not working. It works for around 20,000 files only. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

See [the limits in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/about/).

There is no limit on the number of rows in a table, except as imposed by disk space.

There is no limit on the number of rows that can be loaded by `COPY`.

It's really not possible to give you any better answer if you don't provide basic information like:

- the **exact text** of any error message
- The exact PostgreSQL version from `SELECT version()`
- Anything informative from the PostgreSQL log files

It's OK if you post the original message that's shown in translated form, if you're running PostgreSQL on a computer in Hindi. I can look it up in the translation files to reverse-translate it or use Google. (I can muddle through in a few languages, but my Hindi is limited to "Namaste", "Haan", "Nahin", etc).

Please post a *new, more detailed question* with the appropriate information. Remember, we can't see your screen. We don't know anything you do not tell us.

Comment: I am inserting values from xml file to postgressql using copy from stdin. The total number of files is 400000. When i try to insert, it proceeds without any error. But nothing is inserted. When i try with 20000 files to insert, it is inserted successfully without any issues.

Comment: Show the command(s) run, etc, then. Edit your question to add that information, then comment here. It might also help to look at the PostgreSQL server error log, see if there is anything useful there.